# Issue with mouse on mac and vertical scrolls

Tags: css, mouse

When using the mouse-pad of mac, where no USB mouse is connected, vertical scrolls floats above divs without "stealing" part of their width. Sometimes I care for the inner width to be in-lined with another div's width (one that has no scrolling bars).

But when I do connect a USB mouse, the vertical scroll is painted by the browser as part of the element, stealing pixels.

So if I wish to align widths of 2 divs, one with scroll, one without I can always do calc: 100% - [some scroll width]px. This is known to me.

My issue is that I can't find a CSS media query to find out if the mac thinks its on touch mode (without a USB mouse) or "regular" mode (when a mouse is connected to it).

If the solution must be in JS, please write the solution but try to avoid the messiness of sniffing use agents.

Thanks.